# Qt Text Selection White Line and Text Width

Tags: c++, qt, textselection

I want to customize the text Selection in QTextEdit, I want two things:

1. Remove white spaces/lines when selecting.
2. Be able to choose the width of the selection, either the widget width 
   or the text width.

**White Spaces/Lines :**

Typically, what I would like is that : (from Bear app) :

Bear Text Selection

[image]

While using QTextEdit widget, I've noticed that when I select the text, there are white lines between selected lines :

White Lines Issue

[image]

To fix this, I tried some things:

I have set some colors to the current QTextBlockFormat and the QTextCharFormat to see the precise dimension of each. It seems that the problem comes from the QTextBlockFormat but I don’t know how to fix it.
(`yellow` = `QTextCharFormat`, `red` = `QTextBlockFormat`)

Text Selection With colors

[image]

I’ve tried to change the lineHeight with `QTextBlockFormat::setLineHeight(…);` 
But when I do so, the selection doesn't select the blank spaces :

Line Height

[image]

**Selection Width :**

The second problem is that when selecting the text the full line is selected 
(See image 1).
I would like to select only the text, like in Photoshop :

Photoshop Selection

[image]

I tried with stylesheet : `show-decoration-selected` but it seems to only work with QListView.

Comment: If you are able to rewrite `PySide` into `C++`, (Probably you can understand it because you can understand 'C++'), I can meet your requirements. Is it good?

Comment: @ben5blg any luck in figuring out a solution?