# How to remove empty space between adjacent selected lines?

Tags: qt, qt5, qplaintextedit

I have a `QPlainTextEdit` and whenever I select some text, there is empty space between the adjacent selected lines (see image below). I suspect that this is related to the line height, but so far I haven't been able to find a solution. Any suggestions?

[image]

For reference, I'm using Qt 5.15.0 on Mac.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on linux. And AFAIK you can't change line-height using style sheet. Only way to do that is using `QTextBlockFormat`

Comment: Agree, line-height css won't work. Not sure why it only affects Mac. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50823636/2055281) is another similar question without answer from two years ago.